# Query all channels with unread messages by an specific user?

Tags: getstream-io

I would like to recover all the channels that have unread messages by a specific user. From the docs, I was only able to find the count of unread messages and the count channels with unread messages for the current user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want get all the channels where currentUser is member and sort them by unread_counts desc:

```
const result = await client.queryChannels(
            { members: { $in: [currentUser] } },
            { unread_count: -1 },
        );
```

it is also possible to sort by has_unread:
(in this case it doesn't matter the number of unread messages, any channel with unread messages weight the same for sorting)

```
const result = await client.queryChannels(
            { members: { $in: [currentUser] } },
            { has_unread: -1, last_message_at: -1 },
        );
```

please take a look at our [tests](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-js/blob/eed8a0b1b4042074baec79165c82c10e948c954d/test/channels.js#L648) for more info

Comment: Are there any best practice tips for handling message.new event?

Comment: For Flutter it also works in `StreamChannelListController` params like this: 
`channelStateSort: [const SortOption('unread_count'), const SortOption('last_message_at')],`. 
Would be great to have it mentioned in documentation or as Enum in code, because I can't see such field in Explorer, so it is not obvious what fields can be used.